# Анимация прокручивания картинок

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Здравствуйте, есть сайт https://templated.co/retrospect.

Как можно сделать такую же анимацию прокручивания картинок, как и на данном сайте?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это не javascript , это обычный `background-attachment:fixed;`

> смотреть на весь экран

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.item1,
.item3 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.item2,
.item4 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background: #fff;
}

.item1 {
  background: url(http://wallpaperscraft.ru/image/plity_bereg_more_pasmurno_temnota_55483_2560x1080.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.item3 {
  background: url(https://www.motto.net.ua/pic/201209/1920x1080/motto.net.ua-18427.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="item1 item"></div>
<div class="item2 item"></div>
<div class="item3 item"></div>
```

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: если помог отметьте решением